# Why is my image not displaying in my web page?

Tags: html, image, webmatrix, webmatrix-2

I modified the _SiteLayout.cshtml file in my WebMatrix project so that it contains this line:

```
<p class="site-title"><a <img src="~/Images/Thumbnails/Landscapes/Fall_2012 10 14_0702_th.jpg" />your logo here</a></p>
```

...but the image is not displaying. Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
<a <img src="(snip)" />your logo here</a>
```

You should have:

```
<a><img src="(snip)" />your logo here</a>
```